# Refresh aliases and functions after defining new aliases and functions?

Tags: bash, terminal, alias, bashrc, function

When I define a new alias in `.bash_aliases` file or a new function in `.bashrc` file, is there some refresh command to be able immediately use the new aliases or functions without closing the terminal (in my case xfce4-terminal with a few tabs open, many files open and in the middle of the work)?

Comment: Note that there is no command that will made that new command known in all your open terminals/tabs.  You'll have to do the `. .bashrc` or `source .bashrc` in every shell you have open.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Sourcing the changed file will provide access to the newly written alias or function in the current terminal, for example:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

An alternative syntax:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Note that if you have many instances of bash running in your terminal (you mentionned multiple tabs), you will have to run this in every instance.

Comment: `source` is csh-derived.  The bourne shell way is `. .bashrc`.

Comment: That's interesting that this doesn't work when I define `alias prg='prg.py'` . I have to close terminal.

Comment: "you will have to run this in every instance." - Note that zsh users can set TMOUT and TRAPALRM appropriately to stat and (if necessary) re-source ~/.zshrc once per second, or at any other reasonable interval.  I don't believe bash can do this, though.

Answer (score 8):

Typing `. ~/.bashrc` at the command line will run `.bashrc` and so any functions defined in that file will be created.

`.bashrc` itself will then also call and run `.bash_aliases` (**if** it exists) if `.bashrc` has this code in it:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

whereas using `. ~/.bash_aliases` alone (at the command line for example) will just try and run `.bash_aliases` without involving .bashrc and will give an error if the file doesn't exist (hence the file check test when in `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you will want to turn an alias into a function, but when you source the bashrc file, a weird error may occur:

```
. ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line 38: `hello_world() {'
```

This may be happening because the alias name is clashing with the name of the newly defined function. As far as I know, to avoid this one needs to unalias everything, then source the bashrc file:

```
bash-4.3 $
unalias -a && . $HOME/.bashrc
```