# Modifying bashrc with xrandr doesn't work?

Tags: bashrc

I added the following line to my bashrc:

```
alias b="xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness"
```

When I open another terminal and run `b`, `b 0.1`, or `b 1` it says that command "b" is not found.

I have a similar line for vim that works fine though:

```
alias v="vim"
```

What gives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh aliases and functions after defining new aliases and functions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22919/refresh-aliases-and-functions-after-defining-new-aliases-and-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply changes , run :

```
source .bashrc
```

Also you can log out then log in instead.